# Is it possible to define record batches in Apache Arrow based on time bounaries instead of number of records?

Tags: pyarrow, apache-arrow

Reading up on [Apache Arrow](https://arrow.apache.org/), I've come across the notion of Record Batches, which as the name implies, batches multiple records to enable stream processing. I.e.: processing records per batch instead of having to receive the entire stream.

The examples that I've seen create a new Record Batch for each X number of records. Is it also possibly to create Record Batches by other criteria? Specifically I'd like to group records of the same hour in the same Record Batch. In other words: allow for Record Batches to be created by some configurable time boundary.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A record batch is a group of columns where each column has the same length.  You can divide a table (or a record batch) into smaller batches using any criteria you want.

I'm not sure if you are building up the batches or taking an existing table/batch and breaking it into smaller batches.

At the moment you will have to do the grouping yourself.  Here is an example using Pandas to take a dataframe with random dates and turn it into a table where each month has its own record batch.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import pyarrow as pa

def random_dates(start, end, n):

    start_u = start.value//10**9
    end_u = end.value//10**9

    return pd.to_datetime(np.random.randint(start_u, end_u, n), unit='s')

start = pd.to_datetime('2015-01-01')
end = pd.to_datetime('2018-01-01')
dates = random_dates(start, end, 10000)

df = pd.DataFrame({'dates': dates})
sub_dfs = [sub_df for _, sub_df in df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='dates', freq='M'))]
tables = [pa.Table.from_pandas(sub_df) for sub_df in sub_dfs]
batches = [batch for table in tables for batch in table.to_batches()]
table = pa.Table.from_batches(batches)
```

There is work being done on a `group_by` [compute function](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/compute.html) inside pyarrow as part of https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARROW-11591 .  Once that is finished you would be able to use pyarrow expressions to partition your table instead of pandas.